# Log4j 1.2.15 ExpressionFilter regex

Tags: java, regex, xml, log4j

I'll preface this by saying I have to use Log4j 1.2.15 unfortunately, please don't suggest I upgrade. I do, however, have access to the Extras companion version 1.1.

I am trying to use an `ExpressionFilter` to match any message that contains at least one '-' symbol followed by any number of digits 0-9. 
For example: `-03928474` or `--27646` etc.

EDIT:
Example of full string:
`<ClassName---0182364759> xxx this is a debug message`

I want to match part of this.

I am using the following expression: `MSG LIKE [-]{1,}[0-9]{1,}`

This should serve my needs based on every regex building site I have tried. Note that I tried `\d{1,}` instead of `[0-9]{1,}` but Log4j would remove the \d from the expression (I have debug turned on).

The other `ExpressionFilter`s in the `Appender` work as expected so I do not think this is a problem with the structure of the `Appender`.

This is the one that doesn't work:

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="(MSG LIKE [-]{1,}[0-9]{1,})" />
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
</filter>
```

in the same appender on the next line, DOES work:

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="(LEVEL >= WARN)" />
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
</filter>
```

This must be specified in xml.

I know it's a long shot, but is anyone familiar with the peculiarities of the way Log4j 1.2 handles regex or is able to point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` is understandable, but using `{1,}` instead of `+` is kind of ridiculous. Also, I don't know why you are putting `-` inside square brackets. Anyway, can you provide some of your input strings in the answer? It's hard to debug your problem when we don't know what you're matching against.

Comment: I already included some examples: "For example: `-03928474` or `--27646` etc."

Comment: Is that the entire line? Your pattern contains `MSG LIKE ...`

Comment: Fair enough, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it turns out that the LIKE rule in Log4j 1.2 uses `matcher.matches()` which matches the entire string, whereas I wanted to only partially match the string.

The solution was as follows:

`.*-+[0-9]+.*`

This matches any number of non-newline characters before and after the partial match I want.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the full solution XML configuration